# regex match on words that start with percent

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have a regex that matches well for any new word in a text box:

```
return string.substring(0, area.selectionStart).match(/[\wäöüÄÖÜß]+$/);
```

but I now want to match only when preceded by a '%' symbol, and I don't want to include the % in the match.  This is the only condition I want to add everything else works exactly as it should.

I have tried just about everything I can find, but I think I am over complicating it with crazy regEx patterns...

Sincere thanks for any help. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will have to include it in the match (as there is no look-behind in JS regex), but use a capturing group with the rest and use the captured text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%([\wäöüÄÖÜß]+)\b
```

You use can this and grab the `capture` or `group`

Comment: @ambe5960 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression